# Confused about testing an interface implementing method in C++.. how can I test this?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, tdd

Please, consider the following (I'm sorry for the amount of code; but this is the minimal example I could think of...):

```
class SomeDataThingy
{
};

struct IFileSystemProvider
{
    virtual ~IFileSystemProvider() {}
    //OS pure virtual methods
}

struct DirectFileSystemProvider
{
    //Simply redirects the pure virtuals from IFileSystemProvider to OS functions.
}

struct SomeDataBlock
{
    //Stored inside SomeDataThingy; contains specific data
    SomeDataBlock(const SomeDataThingy& subject, const IFileSystemProvider& os = DirectFileSystemProvider())
    {
        //Calculate some data from the Operating System based upon a filename stored in SomeDataThingy.
    }
};

struct IFilter
{
    virtual ~IFilter() {}
    virtual int Matches(const SomeDataThingy&) const = 0;
    virtual void Calculate(SomeDataThingy&) const = 0;
};

class SomeFilter : public IFilter
{
    int Matches(const SomeDataThingy& subject) const
    {
        if (!Subject.Contains<SomeDataBlock>())
            return UNKNOWN;
        else
            return /* This filter matches */
    }
    void Calculate(SomeDataThingy& subject) const
    {
        std::auto_ptr<SomeDataBlock> data(new SomeDataBlock(subject));
        subject.Install<SomeDataBlock>(data);
    }
};
```

I would like to test `SomeFilter::calculate`, here. The problem is that the constructor for SomeDataBlock calls out to the filesystem. SomeDataBlock itself is tested by a mock `IFileSystemProvider`. However, I don't have a simple way to inject the mock into `SomeFilter::Calculate`; and unfortunately I cannot change the `IFilter` interface to allow the mock to be passed as an argument to `Calculate`, because there are other filters for which such a mock would not make any sense.

How can I test `Calculate`?

Comment: Can you subclass `SomeDataThingy` and use that?

Comment: @the-alchemist: How would `Calculate` know which `SomeDataThingy` to instantiate at that point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you modify the constructor of SomeFilter?  If so, you can inject IFileSystemProvider that way.

```
class SomeFilter : public IFilter
{
public:
    SomeFilter(const IFileSystemProvider& fs = DirectFileSystemProvider())
        : fs(fs)
    {
    }

private:
    int Matches(const SomeDataThingy& subject) const
    {
        if (!Subject.Contains<SomeDataBlock>())
            return UNKNOWN;
        else
            return /* This filter matches */
    }
    void Calculate(SomeDataThingy& subject) const
    {
        std::auto_ptr<SomeDataBlock> data(new SomeDataBlock(subject, fs));
        subject.Install<SomeDataBlock>(data);
    }

    IFileSystemProvider fs;
};
```

You could also create a public member on SomeFilter to allow the user to provide IFileSystemProvider, before calling Calculate, but after constructing the object.

Comment: I think modifying the constructor is the way to go.

Comment: This is one of those solutions that just slaps you in the face, and makes you wonder... .why the hell didn't I think of that? :P

Comment: @Billy: Don't feel too bad.  I had the exact same feeling when I ran into this solution for a very similar (though slightly different) problem.  My problem involved the composite design pattern, and how I could customize the object without polluting the abstract interface.